# Should I divide the user into two tables

Tags: java, sql, spring, spring-boot, rest

I am developing a Spring Boot application for RestApi, I suppose the question has nothing to do with Spring Boot but, I would like to indicate that. Anyway, I have an application that registers users. The registration process works as follows;

1. Supply email and password
2. Verify your email
3. Fill in the remaining parts (username, full name, gender, etc.)

I have a table named `app_user`. In this table `email`, `password`, `username`, `gender`, etc. are non-null properties.

Here is the question:
In the first step user only supplies an `email` and `password`. I need to save that information in the table. However, since `username`, `gender`, etc. are also required properties. When I try to save them I get an exception. After saving that information, I ask for email verification, then I need the remaining parts.

I found the solution by dividing the `app_user` table into two parts. The first table, `user_id`, `email`, `password`. The second table, `user_id`, `username`, `gender`, `fullName`, `createdAt`, etc.

Actually, saving the same entity's information in two separate tables bothered me. I am not satisfied with this solution. So, I am asking for a better one, or is that the correct way to do this process?

Comment: Not sure what your actual question is. You had a problem and you found a solution. You are not satisfied with this solution? Some code would also be nice.

Comment: Question updated. thanks for the warning.

Comment: Dividing the app_user table into two parts, as you suggested, is a valid approach. However, you could also consider using nullable properties in the app_user table, such as username, gender, and fullName. This way, you can save the email and password in the first step, and update the user information once it is available.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a bit hard to give a very good answer because it heavily depends on your actual business logic. But with this kind of multistep process where in the end all fields are mandatory there are two ways to go about it:

1. Keep results of each step in a separate table (like you have done).
2. Keep some fields nullable and based on which fields are null and which are not you can deduce to which step the user has gotten (and therefor block further access if it's not far enough) or keep some kind of special field with a status where user has gotten.

With option two no matter how you actually solve it, lot of the validation and business logic will be in code level in your app.

Also with option two the negative is that it might be bad practice to mix authentication credentials and usual profile information. It doesn't have to be but you have to be careful, what you fetch and update from database on which business flows (usual profile update vs password update or authentication).

Comment: thank you I'll go with the first solution :)